# How to fix faces and uv map?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, uv, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

Trying to model a conversation heart in blender and everything was going well until it was time to mark the seams and i saw that the top part of the heart where the text is has multiple faces when I only need one.

I've tried to dissolve, merge, and delete edges but nothing works and the UV map is an absolute mess. I would like the finished product to be something with two areas/channels for coloring (one for the actual 3d letters and one for the main cake). any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the letters are part of the top face, you can't avoid the edges connecting the letters to the edges of the heart shape. But you could actually separate the letters mesh, it would not make any difference, and you could have one unique face forthe heart if it matters to you